# Java + Selenium : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: selenium, java

I'm using selenium 3.0.1 and java client library 3.0.1. I'm using the following code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class UserActions2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();
    System.out.println("The current URL is " + str);
    }
}
```

And getting the error after FireFox launch

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at Actions.UserActions2.main(UserActions2.java:20)
```

I have no clue for this error. I checked online, But there is  No help.

Comment: At what line of code is this exception thrown? I would suggest you to wait before fetching the  `String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();` so that the webpage is loaded.

Comment: @Alok The exception is thrown immediately opening FireFox.

Comment: Your question doesn't include 20 lines of code but your error is on line 20 according to the stack trace. What line of code is actually throwing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I have run given above code and its running fine.***

> Mostly here might have configuration problem.

**Working configuration of my system :**

1. JDK 1.8 installed and added JAVA_HOME env variable and in path. [Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)
2. Selenium Webdriver version 3.0 + [Download](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)
3. Firefox latest version (v50 or more) [Download and Install](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)
4. Download latest Geckodriver from [Here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases). And put is in root directory of your project. If code is require path of Geckodriver then [follow this](http://learn-automation.com/use-firefox-selenium-using-geckodriver-selenium-3/)

**My Working code  :**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class UserActions2
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.navigate().to("https://www.google.co.in/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        String str = driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println("The current URL is " + str);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
 }
```

Comment: The problem existed because I included geckodriver.exe in the referenced libraries of the project. Anyway, I fixed the problem.